# Auto computation in retrieving a data from database

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in computation in percentage and the pure price. For example I stored 300 in database and I putted 10 percent for that price. So the sum is 330 stored in database. If I retrieve it and change my percent to 1 percent the computation is 361. The previous data of my percentage is always storing and it sums the new percentage I inputted. Any one can help me. I am a begginner in JQuery language. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
    var textbox = $("#txtTaxPercent");
        var ResultTextbox = $("#txtfctTaxValue");
        var PriceTextbox = $("#txtPurePrice");
        var pricetotal = $("#total");
        var pasamame = $(".expense_cost");

            $([PriceTextbox[0]]).bind("change keyup paste", function(e) {
                totalItemExpence();
                mytotal();
            });  

            $([textbox[0]]).bind("change keyup paste", function(e) {
                mytotal();  
            });  

            function mytotal()
            {
                $("#txtfctTaxValue").val(0);
                var Result;
                if(PriceTextbox.val()!=="" ){
                    Result1 = (parseFloat(PriceTextbox.val())) * (parseFloat(textbox.val() / 100));
                    Result = (parseFloat(PriceTextbox.val())) *  (parseFloat(textbox.val() / 100)) + (parseFloat(PriceTextbox.val()));


                }

                else{
                    Result = 0;
                }
                Result = parseFloat( Result) + ntotal;
                pricetotal.val(Result);
                ResultTextbox.val(Result1); 

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using console.log at numerous places in your code to output your important variables to see where things are going wrong.  It's a quick troubleshooting practice that I use all the time.

You may also want to consider adding `alert("got into function XYZ")` to help you know what code is possibly being skipped do to possible faulty conditional statements.

Small steps are the best steps when troubleshooting.  Keep it simple.